# UIScrollview is not scrolling beyond UIView height even though UIView frame is increased

Tags: ios, iphone, uiscrollview, autolayout, xcode-storyboard

I am trying to create a screen where scrolling is required in iphone 3.5 inch screen . I have attached images which contain the configuration of uiviewcontroller , uiscrollview , uiview . The problem is eventhough the height seems to increase , when i run iPhone 4s , some part of scroll is hidden beyond the UIView (Although uiview height shows 700 when i print the height in console) . What might be the problem ? Please help me ?[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you add some details about your constraints? It seems like their are not configured right, from the red mark in your storyboard

Comment: I have added the constraints and also the red mark is now gone . but still 20 % of the bottom view is hidden

Comment: you should read this part of tutorial first . .[UIScrolView and Autolayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AutoLayoutbyExample/AutoLayoutbyExample.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH5-SW2)

Comment: @Atom i think this the issue of the auto layout that you give to the view do one thing remove the bottom constrain and your problem may be solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the information and suggestions . Now it is working correctly . What i did is

1. set scroll view top ,left , right , bottom aligned to superview
2. Set content view of scroll view to top , left , right , bottom aligned to scrollview
3. set the content view of the scroll view to "Equal Heights" and "Equal widths" to the top superview.
4. Then i set the equal height constraint to have low priority of 250

   Now i can scroll whenever required based on the size of the phone screen :)

Answer (score 1):

You have constraints that have negative values. On the last screenshot, which I assume are the constraints from the view inside the scrollView, the bottom offset to the superview is -400.

I think this is why you don't see the entire view because the bottom offset is negative. Try setting this value to 0, this should fix it.

If this does not fix your problem, maybe you could specify for which view the constraints from the images are.

Let me know how it goes! Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

When you work with `UIScrollView` and `AutoLayout` it's always tricky.

You have to add all your subviews to one `UIView` and add that view to `UIScrollView`.

**Autolayout Constraints you need:**

**For UIScrollView:**

```
Left to Superview
Right to Superview
Top to Superview
Right to superview
```

**For Inner View of UIScrollView (i.e The only view inside ScrollView):**

```
Width & Heigh
Left, Right, Top and Bottom constraint to Superview (i.e. ScrollView)
Also add Horizontal Centre to Superview.
```

And it'll work like charm (Works every time for me at least:)

Answer (score 1):

The contentSize must be larger than the scrollview's frame for there to be anything to scroll. :)

In this case, they're both `(600, 1300)` so change your scrollView's height to `(320,480)`

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit confusing, but as Yuvrajsinh told you, you need to set the auto layout constraints for your scroll view to its 4 sides to the superview. Then do the same with the content of the scrollView, and the most important: **Set a fixed/not related with scrollview height and width for the content**